# how to count rows starting at specific position

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count all rows that infront of a specific ID, so I can output how many entries are infront of the users entry. 
I have no clue how to count the rows, starting at the ID of the user (for ex. ID 10).

How to count from ID 10 to ID 1 where status = unpublished

Thx

Comment: You already have the keywords you're looking for... `COUNT` and `WHERE`.  Have you tried using those in a `SELECT` query?  `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM SomeTable WHERE [your filter criteria]`

Comment: ``$query = mysqli_query($this->dbcon(), "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tickets WHERE resolved = '0'") or die("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Versuche es später erneut. Error: MYSQL_Error");`` I'm already using this but it gives out all results... i dont know how to count only from current ID to the first ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10
AND STATUS = 'unpublished'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This --

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tablename
WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10
AND STATUS = 'unpublished'
ORDER by ID DESC
```

Comment: order by usage is pure unneeded overhead in this query

Comment: @RaymondNijland : it's only for sorting asc or desc

Comment: @SAVe: And how does that sorting affect the results of this query?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM  
WHERE ID = 10 AND status='unpublished';

Comment: oh sorry its for PHP

Comment: Ok above query is for mysql as you had tagged mysql

Comment: @pantel Well, selecting them will return a number of rows, so then you would know how many there were. That makes sense afaik

Comment: @Strawberry: SQL is perfectly capable of counting the matching results and returning just that value.  Selecting all of the data when you only need a calculated result is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @David Maybe so, but that's not to say it 'makes no sense'